# Trying to build an Express Email backend API with authentication

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I have an idea for a backend email API server with authentication. Right now I am just focusing on the authentication part of it and this is what I need some assistance with fleshing out:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const expressSession = require("express-session");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(expressSession(session));

const handleAuth = (req, res, next) => {
if (!req.session.user_id) {
    res.status(200).send({ "authenticated": false, "username": null });
  } else {
    res.status(200).send({ "authenticated": true, "username": req.session.user_id });
  }
}
```

The body of this first router below will have a `username: String`, `password: String` and `passwordConfirmation: String`. So my goal here is to eventually develop a frontend app that will send a post request to that path with a body that has a `username`, `password` and `passwordConfirmation` that will sign up the user for a new user account.

```
app.post('/auth/signup', (req, res) => {
  // Signs up for a new account with the
  // provided username
  res.status(422).send({ username: "Username already in use" });
  res.status(422).send({ username: "Username already in use", 
     password: "Must be between 4 and 20 characters", 
     passwordConfirmation: "Passwords must match" });
});
```

The body of the second router below will have a `username: String` and a `password: String`.

```
app.post('/auth/signin', (req, res) => {
  // Signs in with the provided username
});
```

The body of this third router below will have a `username: String`.

```
app.post('/auth/username', (req, res) => {
  // Checks to see if a username is 
  // already in use
});
```

The fourth router will have no body.

```
app.get('/auth/signedin', handleAuth, (req, res) => {
  // Checks to see if the user is currently 
  // signed in
});
```

The fifth router will have an empty object`{}`.

```
app.post('/auth/signout', (req, res) => {
  // Signs the user out
  res.status(200).send({}); 
});
```

Not just the logic, but whatever anyone can lend a hand with, for example, I want to use Redis, but not sure how it fits into this except that it's an in-memory datastore that can save the emails users sign up with as well as checking to see if a `username` is available.

Comment: "whatever anyone can lend a hand with" makes this rather too broad. The idea with Stack Overflow is that questions are specific and focussed, and are likely to be things that future readers would be inclined to search for here.

Answer (score 0):

The express-session https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session package may be useful for you.

Then in your sign up route you just need to store the user data wherever you want and store the logged user for your application to know.

```
req.session.user = req.body.username
```

In the sign in route in you just check if the user exists and again, store the logged user.

```
req.session.user = req.body.username
```

In your logout route you just need to delete the session's user

```
req.session.user = undefined
```

To check wether the user is logged in or not you can use an express Router

```
var routerLogged = express.Router();
routerLogged .use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.user) {
        //user logged in, everything ok
        next();
    } else {
       //user not logged in
        res.redirect("/auth/signin");
    }
});
```

And you apply that router to any route that needs a logged user

```
app.use("/user/personalData", routerLogged);
app.use("/whatever", routerLogged);
...
```